# is breaking up large MySql queries beneficial

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table that has about 5.5 million rows of data. Every month I need to reload this data with a new data file. Since it takes a while to remove the old data, I'm adding limit 2000000 to split the job up into chunks. Example:

```
DELETE FROM `list_content` WHERE list_id = 3 limit 2000000
```

My theory is that memory might be released after the query is done, and splitting it into chunks like this might be beneficial in not consuming resources. However I haven't found anything that supports my theory. Is there any benefit to splitting up a query like this instead of just letting it run for 20 minutes?

Comment: Why would memory play a role here? What causes your query to run 20 minutes is 99.9% your mechanical hard disk.

Comment: wouldn't a soft delete be better?

Comment: If you're deleting the records as a transaction, then it frees up any locks at intervals (assuming each delete is in its own transaction), but it has no affect on memory usage... otherwise, if anything, it will be fractionally slower

Comment: I wasn't sure if memory played a role. It seems now in this case it wouldn't. However when I'm loading the data, php will use up memory to store the data before it is inserted into the table. Perhaps I need to take a look at memory management within the php script.

Comment: There are many factors involved here that we don't know about. First is that we don't know what code you used to load the data - there are efficient and inefficient ways to parse a larger file and add its contents to MySQL. The second thing we don't know is your use scenario. But what's definitely true is that memory is not being used for deleting. If you ran that delete query on an SSD instead of regular disk, you'd see huge improvements. Also, soft-delete might be an option, like @DanielA.White suggested.

Comment: I think there may be ways to make my import process more efficient, I was wondering if a long running MySql query might be eating up memory, which for a delete it is not. Would this also be true for an update such as list_id = 1 where list_id = 2? @DanielA.White I didn't think of a soft delete, I think this is a good direction to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly - there is no benefit. Assuming that you're not hitting any physical limits (like the maximum amount of physical memory your OS supports) and that MySQL is a well written program, then no.

A couple things you might consider

(1)

```
DELETE QUICK FROM `list_content` WHERE list_id = 3
```

followed by a

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE `list_content`
```

`DELETE QUICK` will not perform any house-keeping on the index blocks as its deleting. You can then do all the house-keeping at once with the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` statement.

(2)

If you're wiping out the whole table, then load the new data into a new table... call it `list_temp`

```
DROP TABLE `list_content`; -- very quick since this is simple a delete file op
RENAME TABLE `list_temp` to `list_content`; -- also quick since this is a file rename op
```